# How to keep indentation uniform in xcode and eclipse

Tags: xcode, indentation, myeclipse

In our project there are two teams and are using different IDE for development (MyEclipse and Xcode). Is there any way to keep indentation similar in both the IDE, because when we are doing diff it's showing lots of changes only because of indentation.

Answer (score 0):

If they are using the same code base, there should be no differences. If you are comparing copies of the same code base, maybe there are XCode settings that modify tabs when saving code. If you are using Windows with MyEclipse and OS X with XCode, maybe line endings get switched on save. There should be preferences for that, too. There are also preferences for formatting code on save, or you may have plug-ins for cleaning up code. Lastly, there is a preference for using spaces or tabs to indent code.

There are preferences for how code is displayed, such as how many spaces to use for tabs, but this doesn't affect the actual files. So, again, if the same code base is used then there should be no differences. Perhaps you could expand on what you are comparing with what, if this answer doesn't help.